# Show that $f(X)$ has a dense subset.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X$ be a topological space which has a dense countable subset $D$, and suppose $f\colon X \to Y$ a continuous function. Show that $f(D)$ is dense countable in $f(X)$.

Comment: i am trying to prove that $f(D)$ is dense in $f(X)$ but I can not...

Comment: I suspect there's a "countable" missing somewhere. Every set has a dense subset, for example itself. Yes, looking at $f(D)$ is right. Which characterisations of continuous maps do you know?

Comment: @DanielFischer, I think I have interpreted it correctly.

Comment: @dfeuer One of the two likely interpretations. The other one would be $X$ separable implies $f(X)$ separable, without mentioning $f(D)$. But considering OP's comment, it's certainly not wrong.

Comment: yes.. it is enumerable

Comment: Daniel Fischer give me a hint ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you've decided that $f(D)$ is a good candidate. (Right on target with that one.) Since $f$ maps $D$ onto $f(D)$ and $D$ is countable, then so is $f(D)$. To show that it is dense, consider any non-empty relatively open subset $U$ of $f(X),$ meaning that there is some non-empty open subset $V$ of $Y$ such that $U=V\cap f(X).$ What can you say about $f^{-1}(U)$ by continuity? Since $D$ is dense and $f^{-1}(U)$ is non-empty (why?), what can you conclude from this?

Comment: sorry... it is dense countable subset..

Comment: Answer altered to reflect that.

Comment: I've tried this several times.. thanks

Comment: What does continuity tell you about $f^{-1}(U)$?

Comment: it is a open of X...

Comment: Yes, indeed! Now, since $U$ is a non-empty subset of $f(X),$ then there is some $x\in X$ such that $f(x)\in U,$ so $x\in f^{-1}(U),$ and so $f^{-1}(U)$ is non-empty and open in $X$. Since $D$ is dense in $X$, and since $f^{-1}(U)$ is non-empty and open in $X,$ what can we conclude?

Comment: $f^{-1}(U) \cap D \neq 0$

Comment: Right! That means that there is some $x_0\in D$ such that $x_0\in f^{-1}(U).$ What then can we say about $f(x_0)$ with these two pieces of information?

Comment: is an element of $U$

Comment: True, but that's not all we can say. Remember that $x_0\in D$.

Comment: I can not guarantee that there is sequence converging to $ x_0 $

Comment: only that the converse is true...

Comment: You're getting off track, there. Since $x_0\in D,$ then what can we say about $f(x_0)$?

Comment: is in $f(D)$....

Comment: Exactly! Hence, $f(x_0)\in U\cap f(D).$ Since $U$ was an arbitrary non-empty open subset of $f(X),$ then *every* non-empty open subset of $f(X)$ contains points of $f(D),$ and therefore...?

Comment: true kkkk I'm very stupid

Comment: $f(D)$ is dense -_-

Comment: There we go! That's all there is to it.

Comment: You are very welcome. Please feel free to upvote any answers here that you found helpful, and accept whichever one was most helpful to you.

Comment: and other inclusion? I know that $f(X)$ it is include in clausure of $f(D)$

Comment: Remember that we are only considering the *relative* closure of $f(D)$ in $f(X),$ so the other inclusion is automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be nonempty open in $f(X)$, that is, there is an open set $V$ of $Y$ such that $U=f(X)\cap V$. Then $f^{-1}(U)= f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ and is nonempty, hence intersects $D$.

Answer (score 0):

$f^{-1}\Bigl(\overline {f(S)}\Bigr)$ is a closed set containing $S$ as a subset, and is thus a superset of $\overline S$. So $\overline{f(S)}\supseteq f\Bigl(f^{-1}\Bigl(\overline{f(S)}\Bigr)\Bigr)\supseteq f(\overline S)$.

**Edit:**

Note that the opposite inclusion is a different story/ballgame/kettle of fish:

If $f$ is closed (maps closed sets to closed sets), then $f(\overline S)$ is closed, and since $f(\overline{S})\supseteq f(S)$, $f(\overline S)\supseteq \overline {f(S)}$.

Conversely, suppose the opposite conclusion holds for all $S$ and let $C$ be closed. Then $f(C)=f(\overline C)\supseteq \overline{f(C)}\supseteq f(C)$. This of course implies that $f(C)=\overline{f(C)}$, so $f(C)$ is closed.

So in fact the opposite inclusion is equivalent to $f$ being *closed*, rather than the original which is equivalent to $f$ being *continuous*.

Comment: and other inclusion?

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva, I edited by answer to explain why the other inclusion does not follow from continuity.

Comment: don't i know if $f$ it is closed...

Comment: @JarbasDantasSilva, you don't need to. Can you see why? That whole section about the reverse inclusion is irrelevant to your actual question.